# Error : выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением. Что значит ошибка?

Tags: c, указатели, calloc

Программа должна выделять память для квадратной матрицы

```
#include<stdlib.h>
bool WidPam(int** X, int str, int sto) 
{
    if (!(X = (int**)calloc(str, sizeof(int*))))
    {
        printf("Недостаточно памяти\n");
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str;i++) 
    {
        if (!(/*Курсор стал сюда*/(X + i) = (int *)calloc(sto, sizeof(int))))
        {
            printf("Недостаточно памяти\n");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего вместо `(X + i)` Вы хотели написать `X[i]` ну или `*(X + i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка значит, что `X + i` в левой части присваивания - это бессмыслица. Что вы пытались достичь своей попыткой присвоить что-то в  `X + i`?

Результат выражения  `X + i` не является lvalue. В него нельзя ничего присвоить.